# Kotlin destructuring declaration: passing destructured values directly as parameters

Tags: kotlin

This code should hold a good example:

```
data class Person(val id: String, val fname: String, val lname: String, val age: Int)

data class Capsule(val lname: String, val age: Int)

fun fetch(p: Person) = Capsule(p.lname, p.age)

data class Family(val father: Person?, val mother: Person?, val children: List<Person>)
```

This is a normal destructuring syntax:

```
fun test1(p: Person): Person {
    return with(fetch(p)) { Person(p.id, p.fname, lname, age) }
}
```

But sometimes we have more than one destructuring declaration:

```
fun makeClassicFamily(father: Person, mother: Person, son: Person, daughter: Person): Family {
    val (fatherLname, fatherAge) = fetch(father)
    val (motherLname, motherAge) = fetch(mother)
    val (sonLname, sonAge) = fetch(son)
    val (daughterLname, daughterAge) = fetch(daughter)
    return Family(
            Person(father.id, father.fname, fatherLname, fatherAge),
            Person(mother.id, mother.fname, motherLname, motherAge),
            mutableListOf(
                    Person(son.id, son.fname, sonLname, sonAge),
                    Person(daughter.id, daughter.fname, daughterLname, daughterAge))
    )

}
```

As you can see, we have to name our variables differently to avoid conflicting variable declarations, I am looking for a way to achieve something like this:

```
fun makeAnotherFamily(father: Person, mother: Person, son: Person, daughter: Person) =
        Family(
                Person(father.id, father.fname, fetch(father).function_in_need()),
                Person(mother.id, mother.fname, (lname, age) <- fetch(mother) ),
                mutableListOf(
                        Person(son.id, son.fname, fetch(son) as (lname, age)),
                        Person(daughter.id, daughter.fname,  with(fetch(daughter)){(lname, age)}))
        )
```

The function `makeAnotherFamily` has syntax errors for `fetch(person)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your method

```
fun test1(p: Person): Person {
    return with(fetch(p)) { Person(p.id, p.fname, lname, age) }
}
```

does not have destructuring expression, but has function block with receiver of `Capsule`

Unfortunately in Kotlin you can't destruct return type directly as parameters.
If you want to have expression body inside your `makeClassicFamily` function you can also do the same as you did in `test1` using `with`:

```
fun makeAnotherFamily(father: Person, mother: Person, son: Person, daughter: Person) =
    Family(
        father = with(fetch(father)) { Person(father.id, father.fname, lname, age) },
        mother = with(fetch(mother)) { Person(mother.id, mother.fname, lname, age) },
        children = listOf(
            with(fetch(son)) { Person(son.id, son.fname, lname, age) },
            with(fetch(daughter)) { Person(daughter.id, daughter.fname, lname, age) }
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would just do this:

```kotlin
fun makeClassicFamily(father: Person, mother: Person, son: Person, daughter: Person) =
  Family(father, mother, listOf(son, daughter))
```

There's no need for `Capsule` in the example you've given, especially the way you're using it. If you're going to do some operations on the names and ages, you might need to use destructuring declarations, but even then, you could just have directly done this:

```
val (fatherId, fatherFName, fatherLName, fatherAge) = father
```

instead of using `Capsule` for `lname` and `age` and then explicitly accessing `id` and `fname`.

If you want to create new `Person` objects, you can also use the [`copy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#copying) method available on instances of data classes, although you shouldn't need to here, considering they're all immutable.